# Google results show .info domain instead of .com

Tags: seo, google, domains, cpanel, shared-hosting

I am on shared hosting currently and i registered this account with a .info domain as the main domain.... say MyDomain.info .  However, the site runs from MyDomain.com .

This is a cpanel based shared hosting account.

MyDomain.info has nothing hosted at all... i.e no content files...   MyDomain.com is setup as an Add On Domain and run from /public_html/MyDomain under MyDomain.info

The problem is that when i type MyDomain as the keyword for search in Google , it shows result(s)for  Mydomain.info although this is not the intended site and  has no content hosted on itself.

I tried to solve the issue by issuing a 301 permanent redirect from MyDomain.info to MyDomain.com, however Google keeps on displaying results as mydomain.info as the main site even after 1 month of the redirect.

I want google to index MyDomain.com as the main site and remove MyDomain.info from the results.

Also is this harmful from the seo point of view?  How can i improve the seo if it is?

Answer (score 2):

Sign up for a [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) account and submit an XML sitemap for your .com. Then you need to tell Google you have moved your site using the [address move tool](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=83106).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `301` redirect you should forward the main domain to the addon domain in your registrar account. I know that most unlimited hosting providers force you to register a domain for the primary account.

Forwarding the domain may not remove it from Google's index, what may be better is to do a nofollow on the domains index file assuming that's the only file in the root directory. And block all the robots with robots.txt

Comment: There's no index file in the root directory but a default.html... so should I probably set this one to nofollow? I'd try forwarding at the registrar's end and see what happens. By The way what happens if I move hosting say to a VPS instead of shared and this time set the `MyDomain.example` as the main Account and move all content there... is there anything to lose considering SEO?

Comment: You can delete the default file and all others just place an index.html into that folder and put the noindex meta tag into it plus block robots crawling that domain. You won't lose anything transferring a domain to a VPS and setting it as the main domain.

Comment: @Anagio What do you mean by "forward the main domain"? How is that different from a 301 redirect?